# IOS setUserInteractionEnabled not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch

I have an instance of a UIViewController called SplashViewController.  I added this to the mainwindow in the AppDelegate like this:

```
splashViewController = [[SplashViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SplashScreen" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
splashViewController.view.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
[self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
self.window.frame=[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
window.rootViewController = splashViewController;
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I have to handle touch events in the SplashViewController and I need to turn the userInteractionEnabled YES and NO inside the program.  For some reason my code below have no effect

```
[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]; // YES also have no effect
```

Always fires my touchesBegan function no matter I set YES or NO above.  SplashViewController has an imageview with an image and a simple animation in it.

Where else can I look for why userInteraction is not behaving the way I want?  I tried changing the values set in the Storyboard but no help (anyway the program setting should override the Storyboard setting, I guess).

Any help/pointer please...Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try setting:

```
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

within the "`viewWillAppear:`" method of your SplashViewController object.

Also, are you saving your "`splashViewController`" as an instance variable in your app delegate?  Where do you declare "`SplashViewController * splashViewController;`" in your AppDelegate's .h or .m file?  If it's not being set to an ivar in your app delegate, it's probably being released immediately after you add it.

Comment: Hi Thanks for pointing it out.  I corrected my syntax here.  I was using [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO] and it is a valid syntax.  I assume it should do the same as self.view.userInteractionEnabled=NO;  Tried with this too, but does not solve my issue.  Thank you